# Video feed has every video become the same as the most recent upload when using firebase to populate tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, video, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to populate my VideoFeed with videos to play. But whenever I upload a new video, every video on the feed becomes the same as the last.

Can anyone please help me figure out what is wrong? Using Swift 3.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class VideoFeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,  UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var post: Post!
var posts = [Post]()
var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController! //Sets imagePicker to type UIImagePickerController

var url: URL! //URL for video
var destination: AVPlayerViewController! //Destination for video

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    DataService.ds.REF_VIDEOS.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                print("SNAP: \(snap)") //Prints all snapshots
                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let id = snap.key
                    let post = Post(postID: id, postData: postDict)
                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData() //Need this
    })

}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return posts.count

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //return UITableViewCell()

    post = posts[indexPath.row]

    print(post.videoURL)




    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "videoCell") as? VideoCell {

        cell.configureCell(post: post)

        return cell

    } else {
        return VideoCell()
    }

}

// This function gets the video to play.
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "videoToPlay" {


        let destination = segue.destination as! AVPlayerViewController


        url = URL(string: post.videoURL)

        if let movieURL = url {
            destination.player = AVPlayer(url: movieURL)


            }

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your fire base for-loop isn't iterating over that value.

Comment: Thank you can you help go into detail on that? My snapshot currently prints that specific value

Comment: Your loop is just looping through the whole snapshot that is returned. Just because you're looping through it, and it's returned doesn't mean it's actually set. So where are you setting it in the if let postDict...